# optimizing recursive getJSON method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi friends in my coding i'm using getJSON method to auto fill the text box when the user types the code in one text box, the description of the particular code will be displayed on the other textbox. I'm using more than 20 textboxes in my coding so the getJSON method has to be called 20 times, so i'm typing the code for 20 times is there is any other alternate way to optimize the code my is below .

```
function getCodeDetails1() {
    $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {
        codeid: $("#txtIEcode1").val()
    }, displayResult1);
}

function displayResult(data) {
    if (data.error) { // emp not found
        $("#txtIEdesc1").val(""); // clear fields
        alert(data.error);
    } 
    else { // Found employee. Display details
        $("#txtIEdesc1").val(data.name);
    }
}

function getCodeDetails2() {
    $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {
        codeid: $("#txtIEcode2").val()
    }, displayResult2);
}

function displayResult2(data) {
    if (data.error) { // emp not found
        $("#txtIEdesc2").val(""); // clear fields
        alert(data.error);
    } 
    else { // Found employee. Display details
        $("#txtIEdesc2").val(data.name);
    }
}

function getCodeDetails3() {
    $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {
        codeid: $("#txtIEcode3").val()
    }, displayResult3);
}

function displayResult3(data) {
    if (data.error) { // emp not found
        $("#txtIEdesc3").val(""); // clear fields 
        alert(data.error);
    } 
    else { // Found employee. Display details 
        $("#txtIEdesc3").val(data.name);
    }
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode1" id="txtIEcode1" onchange="getCodeDetails1()" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtIEdesc1" name="txtIEdesc1" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode2" id="txtIEcode2" onchange="getCodeDetails2()" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtIEdesc2" name="txtIEdesc2" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode3" id="txtIEcode3" onchange="getCodeDetails3()" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtIEdesc3" name="txtIEdesc1" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to link your logic to some class instead of multiple ids:

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode1" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc1" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode2" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc2" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode3" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc3" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
```

Then in your js:

```
$(".txtIEcode").each(function(i, el) {
   var $el = $(el),
       $desc = $el.parent().next('td').find(".txtIEdesc");
       $el.on('change', function(){
         $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {
              codeid: $el.val()
         }, displayResult);

         function displayResult(data) {
            if (data.error) { // emp not found
                $desc.val(""); // clear fields
                alert(data.error);
             } 
             else { // Found employee. Display details
              $desc.val(data.name);
          }
       }
   })

});
```

Comment: could you please explain the code i'm bit struggling to understand the code each(function (i,el)) ?

Comment: 'Each' function is simply a loop. It goes through all elements with class txtIEcode and gives them into function(i, el) one by one. The parameters of function are i=index of element, el=element itself (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Basically - no matter how many elements on your page - the logic inside .each(function(i, el)) will be applied to each one.

Comment: there is little problem in this piece of code while alerting  $el it shows [object object]

      $el.on('change', function(){
       alert($el)
      $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {
              codeid: $el.val()
         }, displayResult);

Comment: It's because $el is jQuery object. If you expect to see the value of the input then you should call alert($el.val()). But I would recommend you to open console and use console.log($el) instead of alert.

Comment: I hope the problem is in $desc because it returns undefined while Onchange() can u pls help me out.

Comment: I've just moved your example to jsbin and $desc is fine with the html you provided: http://jsbin.com/yuyufero/2/edit. Is there any change that you have different html structure for some of your txtIEcode->txtIEdesc pair?

Comment: definitely no it is same as like you have posted , the txtIEcode->txtIEdesc pair is same

Comment: now it is returning value from DB but it is not returning to the textbox please help me

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Is your console says something? This solution is dependent from dom and data schema, check if they are the same as in example. Also check if your description input has class 'txtIEdesc'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You have store the file name in variable and passed to arg 

var pageName="ieCodedetails.jsp";
var textBoxId=$("#txtIEcode1");
        getCodeDetails1(pageName,textBoxId);

         function getCodeDetails1(pageName,textBoxId) {

            $.getJSON(pageName, {
                codeid: textBoxId.val()
            }, displayResult1);
        }
```